# Does $\text{Bun}_G$ have the homotopy type of a classifying space in positive characteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, stacks, geometric-langlands

In these [lecture notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/282ynotes/LectureIV-Approaches.pdf) by Jacob Lurie, he identifies the homotopy type of $\text{Bun}_G$ with that of a certain classifying space $B\mathcal{P}_{sm}$ when the group scheme $G$ is over $\mathbb{C}$. Does something analogous hold (e.g. for the $\ell$-adic homotopy type) when the base field is positive characteristic, i.e. $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$?